# What do the moravecs look like in "Ilium" by Dan Simmons?

Tags: dan-simmons, ilium-olympos

What do the moravecs (humanoid machines from the Jovian system) look like in Dan Simmons' *Ilium*?

I am halfway through the book and haven't seen a good description yet as to their appearance.

Comment: If I remember rightly they're named Moravec's in honour of [Hans Moravec](http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/~hpm/) a researcher at the Robotics Institute at Carnegie Mellon University, who has published various books about the future directions of robotics, transcendence and other related stuff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you noticed, the novel is a bit short on specific descriptions. Little bits here and there. For the two main moravec characters:

- Mahnmut is a small humanoid analog...sometimes.
- Orphu is a horseshoe crab...sorta.

> The moravec was not designed for
>   walking — his role was mostly to sit
>   in an exploration submersible,
>   sometimes to swim — and when he grew
>   tired of being a biped, he altered the
>   workings of his joints and spine and
>   padded along like a dog for a while.
>
> *- Ilium, Chapter 22*

These images might be a start...

- [Orphu and Mahnmut](http://lostro.deviantart.com/art/Orphu-and-Mahnmut-158219297)
- [Hamlet meets the dark lady](http://sicknarsh.deviantart.com/art/Hamlet-meets-the-dark-lady-75414040?q=sort%3Atime+favby%3AMidnight-King&qo=1)
- [Mahnmut, etc.](http://m0ai.deviantart.com/art/Mahnmut-etc-71924658)

Ultimately they look like almost anything your imagination can come up with :)